# What are the Oracle Dataguard Implications of Migrating to a PDB?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, dataguard, multi-tenant

If I have an OLTP database with two physical standby instances (one remote) what are the implications of migrating the primary DB to being an Oracle 12c PDB? i.e. Does the process of migrating to being a PDB send a sensible EOR record via Dataguard that will leave the data files on the physical standbys in a state that can be picked up from or would it require a complete backup of the whole CDB with the new PDB plugged in on the primary to be restored to each standby before Dataguard could be resumed?

The Primary DB would already be a 12c non PDB.

Comment: Your DBA should read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/upgrade/upgrading-oracle-database-wp-12c-1896123.pdf couple of times. I am guessing 80-90% of the answer is in there.

Comment: You mean you have a 12c non PDB database and want to plug that into a container database? Or: you are asking about upgrading an 11g configuration to 12c with plugin? With 12c the container has the DG config so a database that plugs in is protected by that right away.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, either you're asking how to upgrade an 11g DataGuard to a 12c pluggable database with DataGuard, or you're asking whether or not you can run a Pluggable Database with DataGuard all toghether. Keep in mind that a major feature of DataGuard is to separate database instances, and that the feature of pluggable databases is to put databases instances close to each other. Maybe your question is about that conflict of setup. Let us know. I'm feeling the way you're asking the question, is the reason why you need a bounty.

Comment: The question is to do specifically with avoiding a full DB backup or massive archive log surge when plugging a PDB. The reason behind using a PDB is for combined user management. There's no reason for there being a bounty other than altruism on the part of the person placing it, the question is in the process of being edited based on these comments.

Comment: OK, so the question is : what is the most elegant way to move a 12c non-PDB to a PDB, when using DataGuard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notes about this in Oracle 12.1.0.2 state that it is not required to move/copy the files from the primary during the plugin. The note also states that in this release the copy of the standby files of the source can be postponed using the standbys=none clause. This makes it possible to plugin a large primary database in a primary container database and perform redo apply/recovery later, when all files are copied into to correct file structure.

see[Handling of Standby Databases during plugin](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1576755.1) note 1576755.1

My conclusion is that in 12.1.0.2 the standby files need to be copied but this is not perse during the plugin of the primary database so it does not cause any extra downtime.

Still I would like to see this tested before I would do this on production.

Comment: Very helpful information but the link provided doesn't go directly to the note listed (it just performs whatever the last search was on your oracle SSO login) and seems to pertain to ASM based installations which is why I discounted this document during my initial search for answers. The situation may be the same for ordinary FS based datafiles but would warrant testing.

Comment: yes, linking notes .... fixed it. The procedure should be tested any way but the ASM/FS should be transparent in this situation.